# The glass window on my in wall fireplace has a green overlay on it

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a fireplace in the wall and it has a glass window when I put the image on the plane behind the glass I'm getting this greenish yellow color is this caused by the reflection how can I get it to just look natural
[image]

Comment: We need more info, like your node setup and the raw image of this plane.

Comment: Maybe try a standard Glass shader as your material. I see you have done a lot of stuff with nodes and what not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do.  It's a trick they call "architectural glass."
The idea is that it doesn't render gloss on diffuse areas to get crystal clear, quick renders.

You've got the order of your shaders swapped.  In your node editor, put **transparent** on top.

[image: ArchitecturalGlass]